# How to edit this datepicker?

Tags: php, mysql, datepicker

I found this very nice datepicker. It allows me to choose between many different variants, but the one I want is not there. I want it to show DD-MM-YYYY. Is it possible to edit it so it shows the numbers as I want?

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

And what's the best way to store it in MySQL? Should I use a timestamp field? In the end I just want it to show the date number, month and year (no time).

Thanks!

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Comment: @Gautam3164 Thanks! What kind of MySQL field should I store this kind of date in: dd-mm-yyyy ? Should I use the one called DATE?

Comment: Yes it is advised to save it as `DATE`

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. You need to use dateFormat option in datepicker function like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        $(".datepickerclass").datepicker({showOn: 'focus',changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});  
    });

</script>
```

and you need to save in mysql as `DATE` type variable

Answer (score 0):

as @Gautam3164 pointed out you would use this format

`$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });`

In terms of storing it in MySQL, I would store it in a `DATE` but this stores the date in the format `yyyy-mm-dd` so you would have to sort the dates you received from your jQuery datepicker.  Something like:

```
<?php
$date = date_parse($receivedDate);
$newDate  = $date[year].$date[month].$date[day];
?>
```

PHP [date_parse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#id").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'});
  });
</script>
```

Change divid to the id of your input element.

If you want to store it in the database in an easy format to order by, search between etc you can just do a `date("y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['inputfield']))` where input field is the name of your input element.

If you wish to output the date again from database in a more readable format (dd-mm-yyyy) then just use the date function again but swap the `y-m-d` to however you want it displayed.